# JS - Перенос объекта в другое поле

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема с JS, в котором я очень слаб, сделал вот такой  код, который выводит уникальный data-id для занесения в БД и добавляет, удаляет элемент из поля, перенося его в другое.

Собственно 2 проблемы:

1. При 1 переносе элементов, все работает как надо, но когда переносишь обратно элемент, происходит что-то странное с занесением в БД уникального data-id
2. Можно ли как-то решить проблему с костылем `var data_post =`, где 10 раз повторяется useritems.shift и 10 раз `botitems.shift` (кажется тут нужен цикл).

---

Вот выполняемый код (только он почему-то не работает тут, может не так настроил)

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addtrade(inv, object) {
  if (inv === "user") {
    if (useritems.length < 10) {
      useritems.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
      $(object).attr("onClick", "removetrade('user', this);");
      $(".tradehave").append($(object));
    }
  } else {
    if (botitems.length < 10) {
      botitems.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
      $(object).attr("onClick", "removetrade('bot', this);");
      $(".tradewant").append($(object));
    }
  }
}

function removetrade(inv, object) {
  if (inv === "user") {
    useritems.pop($(object).attr("data-id"));
    $(object).attr("onClick", "addtrade(\'user\', this);");
    $(".inventoryload").append($(object));
  } else {
    botitems.pop($(object).attr("data-id"));
    $(object).attr("onClick", "addtrade(\'bot\', this);");
    $(".botinventoryload").append($(object));
  }
}

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = {
      w1: useritems.shift(),
      w2: useritems.shift(),
      w3: useritems.shift(),
      w4: useritems.shift(),
      w5: useritems.shift(),
      w6: useritems.shift(),
      w7: useritems.shift(),
      w8: useritems.shift(),
      w9: useritems.shift(),
      w10: useritems.shift(),
      h1: botitems.shift(),
      h2: botitems.shift(),
      h3: botitems.shift(),
      h4: botitems.shift(),
      h5: botitems.shift(),
      h6: botitems.shift(),
      h7: botitems.shift(),
      h8: botitems.shift(),
      h9: botitems.shift(),
      h10: botitems.shift()
    };
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload">
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('user', this);" data-id="1111"></p>
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('user', this);" data-id="1251"></p>
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('user', this);" data-id="4444"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="botinventoryload">
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('bot', this);" data-id="3251"></p>
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('bot', this);" data-id="8018"></p>
    <p class="item" onClick="addtrade('bot', this);" data-id="6543"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="tradesend();" id="button">Обменять</button>
```

Вот, собственно сам код:

`addtrade(inv, object)` - переносит в необходимое поле
`removetrade(inv, object)` - удаляет из необходимого поле, переносит в начальное
`tradesend()` - на кнопке, которая отправляет запрос в БД

```
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];
function addtrade(inv, object) {
    if(inv === "user"){
        if(useritems.length < 10) {
            useritems.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
            $(object).attr("onClick", "removetrade(\'user\', this);");
            $(".tradehave").append($(object));
        } else {
            alertify.error("Ошибка!");
        }
    } else {
        if(botitems.length < 10) {
            botitems.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
            $(object).attr("onClick", "removetrade(\'bot\', this);");
            $(".tradewant").append($(object));
        } else {
            alertify.error("Ошибка!");
        }
    }
}
function removetrade(inv, object) {
    if(inv === "user"){
            useritems.pop($(object).attr("data-id"));
            $(object).attr("onClick", "addtrade(\'user\', this);");
            $( ".inventoryload" ).append($(object));
    } else {
            botitems.pop($(object).attr("data-id"));
            $(object).attr("onClick", "addtrade(\'bot\', this);");
            $( ".botinventoryload" ).append($(object));
    }
}
function tradesend() {
    if(useritems.length > 0){
        var data_post = {w1: useritems.shift(),w2: useritems.shift(),w3: useritems.shift(),w4: useritems.shift(),w5: useritems.shift(),w6: useritems.shift(),w7: useritems.shift(),w8: useritems.shift(),w9: useritems.shift(),w10: useritems.shift(),
            h1: botitems.shift(),h2: botitems.shift(),h3: botitems.shift(),h4: botitems.shift(),h5: botitems.shift(),h6: botitems.shift(),h7: botitems.shift(),h8: botitems.shift(),h9: botitems.shift(),h10: botitems.shift()};
    console.log(data_post);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tradesend.php",
            data: data_post,
            success: function(){
                window.location.replace("/");
            },
            error: function(){
                alertify.error("Ошибка!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alertify.error("Ошибка!");
    }
}
```

Comment: метод `pop` у массива не принимает параметр, он просто удаляет последний элемент массива и возвращает его, то есть эти две записи абсолютно эквивалентны: `useritems.pop($(object).attr("data-id"));` и `useritems.pop();`

Comment: А как тогда поступить можно? Плохо в JS вникаю очень

Comment: я не особо понимаю, что вообще делает код и какая ему соответствует  html разметка, похоже тут половину кода можно выкинуть, но без [mcve], который можно запустить и посмотреть как это сейчас работает, решение может и не подойти

Comment: поправил сниппет, проблема была в экранировании кавычки, теперь работает так как задумывалось?

Comment: Да, именно так и работает, благодарю, ну собственно вот пример работы, мне нужно исправить эту фатальную проблему с data-id, чтобы он заносил именно те data-id которые остались в оранжевых полях после всех махинаций с перенесением и 2 проблема это большое количество строк с .shift, можно ли как-то реализовать это в 1 строку по типу цикла?(w и h обязательны, это ключи для правильного занесения в БД)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка удаления связана с тем, что [функция `pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) удаляет *последний* элемент массива.

В качестве решения можно определить индекс удаляемого элемента, с помощью [функции `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), и затем удалить найденный элемент с помощью [функции `splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Например так:

```
var id = $(object).attr("data-id");
var index = useritems.indexOf(id);
useritems.splice(index,1);
```

По поводу собирания объекта: можно использовать [функцию `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), например так:

```
useritems.reduc(function(acc,el,index){
    acc['w'+(index+1)]=el;
    return acc;
},{});
```

Кроме того, несколько замечаний:

1. Если уж используется jQuery, добавлять обработчики событий стоит тоже с помощью него, а не с помощью атрибут *onclick*/
2. Очень много дублирующегося кода, в котором отличаются по большому счету только массив, с которым производятся операции.
3. Так как обработчики зависят от контейнера, в котором располагаются элементы, имеет смысл использовать делегирование событий и добавить обработчик на сам контейнер с помощью [функции `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), а не конкретный элемент

В итоге все может выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addTrade(items, dest) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave');
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant');

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload">
    <p class="item" data-id="1111">1111</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="1251">1251</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="4444">4444</p>
  </div>
  <div class="botinventoryload">
    <p class="item" data-id="3251">3251</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="8018">8018</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="6543">6543</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="tradesend();" id="button">Обменять</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю за такой подробный ответ, учту, потом проверю, отпишусь